# Color of parallel coordinates plot by group

Tags: r, echarts4r

How can I set the color of a parallel coordinates plot to vary by group?

This example does not work:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars |>
  group_by(gear) |> 
  e_charts() |>
  e_parallel(1:3) |>
  e_color(
    c("red", "blue")
  )
```